# Boost OdeInt cannot set class property when entering integration routine

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I'm using `boost::numeric::odeint` to build a custom integrator.
Other than computing the discrete derivative of the state, I'm computing the output equation during each integration step entering `operator ()`. I do know it's not efficient, but as of now I need it to understand how the library is working.

While debugging, inside the `operator ()` method both `y` and `test` variables are computed fine. But, as soon as the program returns to main loop, `sys` objects has `y` and `test` variables uninitialized.

Below the code is presented and the result that reproduces what discussed.

##### TestSystem.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

const int n = 2; // State size
const int q = 1; // Output size
const int m = 1; // Input size

typedef Vector<double, n> state_type;
typedef Vector<double, m> input_type;
typedef Vector<double, q> output_type;

typedef Matrix<double, n, n> state_matrix_type;
typedef Matrix<double, n, m> input_matrix_type;
typedef Matrix<double, q, n> output_matrix_type;
typedef Matrix<double, q, m> feedthrough_matrix_type;

class TestSystem
{

public:
    state_matrix_type A{ 
        { -4.0, -3.0}, 
        { 1.0, 0.0} 
    };
    input_matrix_type B{ 1.0, 0.0 };
    output_matrix_type C{ 1.0, 1.0 };
    feedthrough_matrix_type D{ 0.0 };

    double test;

    input_type u;
    output_type y;
    void operator() (const state_type& x, state_type& x_dot, const double t);
};
```

##### TestSystem.cpp

```
#include "TestSystem.h"

void TestSystem::operator()(const state_type& x, state_type& x_dot, const double t)
{
    x_dot = A * x + B * u;

    this->y = C * x + D * u;

    this->test = (C * x + D * u)(0);

    cout << "Output computed within integration step: " << endl;

}
```

##### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "TestSystem.h"

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
using namespace cnpy;

const double PI = 3.14159265359;

const int N = 5000;

VectorXd u(N);

#include <boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta4.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_n_steps.hpp>

using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

int main()
{
    VectorXd t(N);

    t = VectorXd::LinSpaced(N, 0.0, 1.0);

    TestSystem sys;

    u = (2 * PI * 200 * t).array().cos() + (2 * PI * 20 * t).array().sin();

    state_type x = state_type::Zero();
    
    // Just one step for example sake
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        input_type _u{ u(i) };
        // _u << u(i);

        sys.u = _u;

        runge_kutta4<state_type> rk;

        rk.do_step(sys, x, t(i), t(1));

        cout << "System object output variable: " << sys.test << endl;
    }
}
```

##### Result

```
Output computed within integration step: 0
Output computed within integration step: 0.00010002
Output computed within integration step: 9.999e-05
Output computed within integration step: 0.00019998
System object output variable: -9.25596e+61
```

Comment: The code doesn't match the output. No code ever prints "Output computed within integration step" - can you add the missing code and perhaps supply expected output?

Comment: Never mind, did it myself, but the output still doesn't reproduce your issue. Can you edit it or figure out what you did differently? Note, the style edits I made do NOT affect the output: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Y5bYG4YY1

Comment: You're completely right. It was much of an excessive edit of the answer: I was deleting some lines of code and I rip off also that cout line. Thank you for the spot!

Comment: I finally realized what you probably expected as output. It would have been really helpful if you had just mentioned it. Until now I was just spinning gears trying to reproduce your indeterminate value output - which wasn't actually part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry if I rolled my answer back. I appreciated a lot your restyle, but, no offence, that is my original code and I'd like to keep it as was. Propose your version, and I'll appreciate it a lot. As far as the output is concerned, please, **don't** edit **mine**. That MIGHT be your output, but it is not the one **I** got (and no, it's not a coincidence, I deliberately left the variable uninitialized). That's why I could accept an answer such as _you're output does not get reproduced_, but it's not really fine to change it with yours.

Comment: I suppose you didn't see my answer yet. And, yes, if your code reproduces the problem, the edit would not have been required :) You're free to edit your question how you see fit, regardless

Comment: The output didn't get reproduced only because I forgot the cout statement. That's the only part that was missing. Thank you again for having it spotted.

Comment: By the way, great answer, thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is passed by value. To force reference semantics, use a reference wrapper:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/cGa8Yc9Yf)**

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using Eigen::Matrix;
using Eigen::Vector;
using Eigen::VectorXd;

int constexpr n = 2; // State size
int constexpr q = 1; // Output size
int constexpr m = 1; // Input size

using state_type  = Vector<double, n>;
using input_type  = Vector<double, m>;
using output_type = Vector<double, q>;

using state_matrix_type       = Matrix<double, n, n>;
using input_matrix_type       = Matrix<double, n, m>;
using output_matrix_type      = Matrix<double, q, n>;
using feedthrough_matrix_type = Matrix<double, q, m>;

struct TestSystem {
    state_matrix_type       A{{-4.0, -3.0}, {1.0, 0.0}};
    input_matrix_type       B{1.0, 0.0};
    output_matrix_type      C{1.0, 1.0};
    feedthrough_matrix_type D{0.0};

    double test;

    input_type  u;
    output_type y;
    void        operator()(state_type const& x, state_type& x_dot, double t);
};

void TestSystem::operator()(state_type const& x, state_type& x_dot, double) {
    x_dot = A * x + B * u;

    this->y = C * x + D * u;

    this->test = (C * x + D * u)(0);
    std::cout << "Output computed within integration step: " << test << std::endl;
}

#include <boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta4.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint/integrate/integrate_n_steps.hpp>

namespace ode = boost::numeric::odeint;

int main() {
    int constexpr N = 5000;
    VectorXd t(N);

    t = VectorXd::LinSpaced(N, 0.0, 1.0);

    TestSystem sys;

    VectorXd u(N);
    u = (2 * M_PI * 200 * t).array().cos() + (2 * M_PI * 20 * t).array().sin();

    state_type x = state_type::Zero();
    
    // Just one step for example sake
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        input_type _u{ u(i) };
        // _u << u(i);

        sys.u = _u;

        ode::runge_kutta4<state_type> rk;

        rk.do_step(std::ref(sys), x, t(i), t(1));

        std::cout << "System object output variable: " << sys.test << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Output computed within integration step: 0
Output computed within integration step: 0.00010002
Output computed within integration step: 9.999e-05
Output computed within integration step: 0.00019998
System object output variable: 0.00019998
```